# Using mixin composition with functions in scala

Tags: scala, function, mixins

I'm trying to use mixin composition using functions, but I have an error in the `apply` method of `obj` object:

Overriding method apply in `trait t` of type `(s: String)String`; method `apply` needs `abstract override` modifiers.

How to solve this error and which is the correct implementacion?

```
trait t extends Function1[String,String] {
  abstract override def apply(s: String): String = {
    super.apply(s)
    println("Advice" + s)
    s
  }
}

object MixinComp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val obj = new Function1[String, String] with t {
      override def apply(s: String) = s
    }
    println(obj.apply("Hi"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't need to use the `abstract` modifier in your `t` trait definition, if you don't call the `super.apply`. And in this particular case I dont see any need for calling super.apply as Function1's apply is abstract. You probably need custom apply implementations. The following code should work.

```
trait t extends Function1[String, String] {
  override def apply(s: String): String = {
    // super.apply(s)
    println("Advice" + s)
    s
  }
}
```

Case1: use the overridden apply method in `t` trait:

```
val obj = new Function1[String, String] with t {} 
obj.apply("hello") // prints: Advicehello
```

Case 2: override the apply method in `t` trait in an anonymous class:

```
val obj = new Function1[String, String] with t {
  override def apply(s: String): String = s
}

obj.apply("hello") // prints hello
```

Comment: this does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem (the reason it complains about the error) is that you can't have an abstract call in your linearization flow (your `t.apply` calls `super.apply`, which is abstract).

Also, the `apply` method you define in the top level anonymous class overrides everything, and does not call `super`, making the `t` being mixed in completely irrelevant.

Something like this would solve both problems:

```
trait t extends Function1[String,String] {
  abstract override def apply(s: String): String = {
    println("Advice" + s)
    super.apply(s) // I rearranged this a little, because it kinda makes more sense this wat
  }
}

 // Note, this extends `Function1`, not `t`, it, just a "vanilla" Function1
class foo extends Function1[String, String] {
   def apply(s: String): String = s
}


// Now I am mixing in the t. Note, that the apply definition 
// from foo is now at the bottom of the hierarchy, so that 
// t.apply overrides it and calls it with super 
val obj = new foo with t
obj("foo")
```